# How can I have different X & sound configuration depending on which user logs in?

Tags: 12.04, sound, xorg, configuration, users

First off: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and the NVIDIA X Server Settings GUI to configure.

I've recently gotten a new LED TV hooked up to my computer - the video card supports two displays.  I would like to create a user "TV" that, when they log in, the default display is the TV and my monitor is disabled.

Using the NVIDIA tool, I only seem to be able to save the settings for all users.  So each time I want to watch on the TV, I have to go and reconfigure.  Not only the X server settings, but also the sound settings (to make sure sound goes out to HDMI and not the computer speakers).

I know there must be a way of easily doing this by dropping the config file into a certain location or something.... please help!